# I have an error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ApproximateTimeSynchronizer'" even if i already used TimeSynchronizer

Tags: ros-hydro, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System information

OS: Ubuntu 12.07
ROS version: Hydro

this the code i just create to be able to use two topics at the same time:

```
import numpy as np
import  message_filters
import rospy
from gps_common.msg import GPSFix
from personalpackage.msg import imu
from personalpackage.msg import GNSS

message = ""

def callback(GNSS,GPS):
        f=open("the_times.csv","a+")
        print("inside callback")
        time_ros= GNSS.header.stamp.secs+GNSS.header.stamp.nsecs*0.000000001
        time_gps= GNSS.time.secs+GNSS.time.nsecs*0.000000001
        time_gps_pps= GNSS.time_clock.secs+GNSS.time_clock.nsecs*0.000000001
        tsmp = time_gps_pps - time_ros
        message="time_ros       time_gps       time_gps_pps        difference between timeGPS & timeGPSPPS\n"
        message=message+str(time_ros)+"\t"+str(time_gps)+"\t"+str(time_gps_pps)+"\t"+str(tsmp)+"\n"
        print(message)
        rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)

def the_times():
        rospy.init_node('the_times', anonymous=True)
        GnssData=message_filters.Subscriber("GPS",GPSFix)
        ImuData=message_filters.Subscriber("GNSS",GNSS)
        print("after filtering")
        ApproSynchron=message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([GnssData,ImuData], 10, 0.1,allow_headerless=True)
        print("after Synchro")
        ApproSynchron.registerCallback(callback)
        print("after Callback")
        rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        the_times()
```

When i execute it i get this error message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "the_times.py", line 51, in 
>     the_times()
>   File "the_times.py", line 41, in the_times
>     ApproSynchron=message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([GnssData,ImuData], 10, 0.1,allow_headerless=True)
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ApproximateTimeSynchronizer'

I already tried the same code using "TimeSynchronizer" and i didn't get any error message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345044/i-have-an-error-%22attributeerror:-%27module%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27approximatetimesynchronizer%27%22-even-if-i-already-used-timesynchronizer/) by [MohamedAkaarir](https://answers.ros.org/users/52061/mohamedakaarir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was simply that i don't have the good version of message_filters library that contains "ApproximateTimeSynchronizer", the default version of message_filters library on hydro distro is 1.10.12.

ApproximateTimeSynchronizer was first introduced in 1.11.4  version of message_filters library.

---

Originally posted by [MohamedAkaarir](https://answers.ros.org/users/52061/mohamedakaarir/) with karma: 16 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0